# Use IF statement in WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to use IF clause within a WHERE clause in SQL Server.
Example:

```
WHERE
A = @param -- → If does not exist then go to the second condition
OR A LIKE SUBSTRING(@param, 1, LEN(@param) - 6) + '%'
```

I have tried using CASE WHEN like this;

```
A LIKE (CASE WHEN @param IS NULL THEN @param ELSE SUBSTRING(@param, 1, LEN(@param) - 6) + '%' END)
```

But it does not work.

Comment: You can't you use AND/OR logic.

Comment: It's fine as it is.

Comment: You need to clarify your logic and ideally provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: what kind of the logic that I can use ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the `CASE` statement within the `WHERE` clause.

```
WHERE
  (
    CASE
      WHEN @param IS NULL THEN 1
      WHEN person = @param THEN 1
      WHEN person LIKE SUBSTRING(@param, 1, LEN(@param) - 6) + '%' THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END
  ) = 1;
```

Comment: Bad idea. Keep current AND/OR based code.